# Which context has the verb "admit" been used in here?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I read a definition of privy in "Merriam Webster" dictionaries which was

> Admitted as one sharing in a secret

I don't think the verb admit means to confess here. Does it mean "to acknowledge" in this context? I am also having trouble in understanding the sentence structure relating to the "as one" part in there.

Comment: You're asking us to analyse the wording of a dictionary definition!

Comment: Yeah,  pretty much. See,  I know it can't be wrong but I don't quite understand the "as one" part. If the verb "admitted" mean "allowed in" there, then the latter part would have been somewhat like "in a secret".

Comment: You were already looking at Merriam-Webster, so you could have looked up [*admit*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/admit):"**2 a** : to allow entry (as to a place, fellowship, or privilege)."

Comment: And *as one* just means *as* ***someone***. It's the gender-neutral, third-person singular pronoun—not the number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case "admitted" means "allowed in". You would be "admitted into a club", and a movie ticket will often say "admit one".

*Admitted as one sharing in a secret*

That means a person is "allowed in" to know the secret, or "allowed in to the group who know the secret"... even if that "group" was only one person.

Comment: I mostly agree with your answer but I don't think the "as one" part means a single person.

Comment: @Kelvin I'm not sure which part you mean, so I'll give two comments. I believe "Admitted as one" clearly refers to a single person being admitted right now. You can't say "We were admitted as one", it would have to be "We were admitted as ones". I also mention the size of the group before the admission: There may have been any number of people who knew the secret, possibly only one person. I didn't want anyone to think "group" had to be plural.